# Poor Perfomance - Android & JNI (C++ image processing with OpenCV)

Tags: android, performance, opencv, image-processing, jvm

I  have an app running on **Android**, which comunicates with **C++** code through **JNI** interface. In the C++ code i'm doing some hard image processing, using **OpenCV**.

For example, making the "hard processing" take me 40 seconds. And it takes the same time in a Morotola Milestone 1 or a Samsung S3 mini.

I have also made some tests in 2 laptops. In this case is a Java App that comunicates with exaclty the same C++ code through JNI. If i run the app in Asus laptop (AMD E-450 procesor) or a Bangho laptop (Intel Core i5) both with 4 GB RAM, i get the same results in seconds. (Note: Processing with the laptops is like 4 or 5 times faster)

I'm a little dissapointed right now. And the question is:

**Is ther any way to get the most of the processor?** (I know i can change the memory settings of the JVM in the laptop, but it doesn´t seem to be a memory problem)

I'm not posting the code, because is very extense. Any help would be really apreciated.

Comment: Desktop processors are quite a bit faster than mobile processors. 4 to 5 times sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

As @zapl mentioned, only 4 to 5 times slower is about what you should expect in the first place. However, there are things to optimize:

1. You could benchmark the 'pain' loop codeblock, and rewrite than in NEON. NEON **intrinsics** should be about 2-4 times faster than unoptimized c/c++ code. NEON **assembly** is often faster than **intrinsics**, but harder to write.
2. Use the latest GCC 4.7 and enable GCC's 'loop unroll' and 'loop vectorization' (not 100% sure GCC does implement loop vectorization for the ARM platform).
3. Use multi-threading (C++11). Almost all mobile processors have multiple cores. Running on four cores is about 2-3.5 times faster than running on a single core.
4. Help the CPU's branch predictor make better judgement on what to process next, by moving if-statements outside of loops.

For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
if (i < middle) 
  // first part
else
  // second part
}
```

Replace by:

```
for(int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
  // first part

for(int i = middle; i < total; i++)
  // second part
```